# Change a label to the text in a text box VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a button, a text box and a label. When the button is pressed I want it to read the value of the text box and place it in the label and then, if possible, delete the text in the text box (set it to nothing "").

Here's what I tried:

```
'Keybind args handler.
Private Sub keyBindBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles keyBindBtn.Click
    keyBindLabel.Text = keyBindBox.Text
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    keyBindBox.Text = ""
End Sub
```

This gives me an unhandled exception when pressing the button.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: A button click event handler doesn't receive a KeyPressEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve said for some reason there was a keyPressEventArgs instead of EventArgs.

Thank you!